# ACC API endpoints: Assign one or more project members directly

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-construction-cloud

I'm trying out the new endpoints added in the ACC API via Postman, which were newly added in version 1.1.0, see [Account Admin V1 Changelog](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/change_history/admin_v1_changelog/). Specifically I am having a problem adding a user to a project, then updating or deleting them.

In all cases 401 - Unauthorized is returned.
[Postman printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Sgk.jpg)

If I follow the [Step-by-step Tutorials](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/tutorials/admin/admin-create-configure-projects/), everything works up to point 3 (option 3B).

Thanks for any advice,
Marek

Answer (score 0):

Kindly indicate the type of Aunthentication you are using and the scopes.
On this page https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/tutorials/admin/admin-create-configure-projects/#before-you-begin
You can see the usage of 3-LO and 2-LO for the endpoints.
If you are using 2-LO you need to use User-Id header to get the token.